# Can indoor cable be run through an exterior wall and into a disconnect box?

Tags: wiring

I’m running 6/3 NM cable from my breaker box inside the house through the studs and then exiting to the outside to tie into a spa disconnect box.

- Can I have the cable come straight out of the wall and tie into the back of the disconnect box on the exterior wall?

Comment: Romex is a brand name, normally referencing Type NM cable, which is not allowed in damp or corrosive locations, which AHJ's where I live would define that as being both. The paper in NM cable has a wicking effect. Clarifying cable type might get better complete responses.

Comment: I've edited to what I assume you meant. Feel free to revise further.

Comment: Externally crossposted [here](https://www.diychatroom.com/f18/romex-coming-out-exterior-wall-how-688603/#post6165687).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the jurisdiction. NM-B cable is not ok for exterior wiring, but a receptacle inset in a wall is 100% ok.

If the box is NEMA 3r rated it may be allowed even as a surface mount. If it is not, cut a hole the size of the box and inset it in the wall then it would be legal again. The box needs to be 3r rated.

It may sound silly but a flush mount box can be inset (I have done this with main panels). At first the inspector was going to red tag it, but when he saw the back of the box was inside the siding he was ok. I have done this several times in the last ~2 years. My boss likes the look better than flush mount but they are a pain in the butt to feed for a main.

Comment: The box I have is "3r" rated.....  https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Spa-Panels-GFCI-Protected-Panels/Eaton/BR50SPAST/product.aspx?zpid=189436

Comment: Check with your local inspector, if surface mount is not allowed inset should work.